# Sequence of continuous $\varepsilon$-isometries in Gromov–Hausdorff convergence

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

I'm reading S. Ivanov's article "*Gromov-Hausdorff convergence and volumes of manifolds*" ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1604389)). In Proposition 1.2 the author shows that given a sequence of compact metric spaces $X_k$ converging in the Gromov-Hausdorff sense to a compact metric space $X$ which is a Euclidean neighborhood retract (ENR), one can always find a sequence of **continuous** $\varepsilon_i$-isometries with $\varepsilon_i\to 0$.

(It is easy to see that one can find such a sequence if one doesn't care that the functions are continuous, for example as in [Burago, Burago, and Ivanov - A course in metric geometry](http://www.ams.org/books/gsm/033) ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1835418))).

I'm struggling with one part of the proof: The strategy is to use that since $X$ is an ENR then there exists an embedding $i:X\to \mathbb{R}^n$ and a retraction $r:U\to i(X)$ where $U$ is an open neighborhood of $i(X)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and define a function $i_k:X_k\to \mathbb{R}$ by

$$i_k(x):= \frac{\sum_{y\in S_k} w_k(d(x,y)) i(f_k(x))}{\sum_{y\in S_k} w_k(d(x,y))}.$$

Here, $f_k:X_k\to X$ is a sequence of $\delta_k$-isometries for some $\delta_k\to 0$, $w_k:[0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ is an arbitrary continuous function which is positive on $[0,2\varepsilon_k)$ and $0$ on $[2\varepsilon_k,\infty)$ where $\varepsilon_k$ is the infimum of the $\delta$'s for which $f_k$ is a $\delta$-isometry and $S_k$ is an $\varepsilon_k$-net on $S_k$.

Now, the author shows that
$ \sup_{x\in X_k}|i_k(x)-i(f_k(x))|\to 0$ as $k\to \infty$ which allows one to define for big enough $k$ a function
$\varphi_k:= i^{-1} \circ r \circ i_k: X_k\to X$.

The claim is that these are in fact the new almost-isometries which are continuous and the distance bewtween $\varphi_k$ and $f_k$ goes to $0$ as $k\to \infty$.

I have tried to show this without success. I am under the impression
that the distortion of $i^{-1}\circ r$ cannot be controlled and so I
am at a loss when I try to see that the distortions of the $\varphi_k$
are actually small and converging to $0$.

> Questions:
>
> 1. Can you help me show that the distance between $\varphi_k$ and $f_k$ goes to zero?
> 2. Could you provide a motivation for the defintion of $i_k$?

Comment: You have a pair of indented paragraphs labelled 'questions', but there is only one question in it.

Comment: I've made the questions explicit thank you.